# React Application state in stores or this.state

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux

In the flux tutorial it says, "Application state is maintained only in the stores." Thus, to me it seems counter-intuitive that react's controller-views also have `this.state` that is kept in sync with the stores via callbacks that call `setState()`.

Wouldn't it make more sense to use the stateful controller-view itself as a store? This way, the only time the word "state" would appear in the app is in stores. And then every non-stateful (or non-store) view would only use `this.props`.

Basically, why do we have views that use `this.state` and stores that manage that state - can't the views manage it themselves? I thought that was the point of the `this.state` variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with having important data owned by the component is that you can't access it externally from that component.

For example, if you decide to start syncing data to the server every 10 seconds, the component shouldn't have to care about that.  You just write a script that gets data from the store and persists it.

Also some data is shared by components that don't have a clear or any relationship.  The most common case of this is the current user.  For example, you may have 3 ways a user can log in, and 5 places where the logged in status and user information affects the view of the page, and two places they can logout from.